# Como creo una lista dentro de una clase en python?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio para un curso de python y me quede estancada y con un par de dudas ya que el profesor hizo mucho mas complicado dicho ejercicio.

Este es mi codigo actualmente

```
from compu import Compu

class Orden(Compu):
    contador_ordenes = 0

    def __init__(self, computadora):
        Orden.contador_ordenes =+ 1
        self.id_orden = Orden.contador_ordenes
        self._computadoras = computadoras

    def agregar_computadora(self, computadoras):
        self._computadora.append(computadoras)

    def __str__(self):
        computadoras_str = ''
        for computadora in self._computadoras:
            computadoras_str =+ Compu.__str__(self)

        return f'''
        orden: {self.id_orden} 
        Lista de computadoras: {computadoras_str}'''

    @property
    def computadora(self):
        return self._computadora

    @computadora.setter
    def computadora(self, computadora):
        self._computadora = computadora
```

Ya tengo creada una clase padre que es `Compu`, con la herencia no tuve ningún problema. Lo que quiero hacer es en una orden (la clase actual) poder añadir un numero de objetos y esos objetos poder listarlos para que se haga la primera orden, con la segunda orden también listarlos y etc. Cuando imprimo este código se imprime correctamente salvo que me aparece la dirección de memoria de (creo) la orden y cuando intento imprimir la segunda orden no puedo directamente.

El código de prueba es:

```
    pc1 = Compu('HP', 'Samsung', '25 pulgadas', 'usb', 'genius', 'tipo c', 'Genius')  
    pc2 = Compu('Lenovo', 'Phillips', '15 pulgadas', 'Tipo USB', 'genius', 'Tipo C', 'sony') 
    orden1 = [pc1, pc2] 
    print(orden1)  
    pc3 = Compu('Lenovo', 'Phillips', '15 pulgadas', 'Tipo USB', 'genius', 'Tipo C', 'sony') 
    orden2 = [pc3]  
    print(Orden(2))
```

La clase Compu también es una clase hija, por lo tanto si empiezo a adjuntar todas las clases se haria una pregunta muy larga. Gracias

Comment: El código tiene errores de sintaxis, y sin `compu.py` no se puede comprobar la solución. Tampoco parece relevante que la clase `Orden` derive de `Compu`, pues no hay ninguna invocación o uso de métodos en la clase padre. Tampoco aportas el código donde se produce el problema. Faltan esos detalles.

Comment: lo único que yo necesito que haga la clase orden es ir aumentando automáticamente cada vez que yo creo una orden, orden 1, orden 2, etc. y que al crear esa orden me la pueda listar! El codigo con el que yo estaba haciendo la prueba de como se imprimia es este:
`pc1 = Compu('HP', 'Samsung', '25 pulgadas', 'usb', 'genius', 'tipo c', 'Genius')

pc2 = Compu('Lenovo', 'Phillips', '15 pulgadas', 'Tipo USB', 'genius', 'Tipo C', 'sony')
orden1 = [pc1, pc2]
print(orden1)

pc3 = Compu('Lenovo', 'Phillips', '15 pulgadas', 'Tipo USB', 'genius', 'Tipo C', 'sony')
orden2 = [pc3]

print(Orden(2))`

Answer (score 1):

Una lista es otro objeto en Python. No hay diferencia con crear otro objeto cualquiera, ya sea dentro de una función o dentro de un método de alguna clase. La sentencia

```
lista = []
```

o

```
self.lista = []
```

es todo lo que se necesita para crear una lista.

Revisemos todo desde un principio, que el modelamiento de clases es un desastre.

Esta es la clase `Computadora`, que describe un equipo (solo capturamos marca y modelo):

```
class Computador:
    def __init__(self, marca, modelo):
        self.marca = marca
        self.modelo = modelo

    def __str__(self):
        return f"PC {self.marca} {self.modelo}"
```

Una orden tiene un número de identificación y una lista de computadores:

```
class Orden:

    numero_orden = 0   # Variable de clase

    def __init__(self, *lista_computadores):
        Orden.numero_orden += 1
        self.id = Orden.numero_orden
        self.lista_computadores = lista_computadores

    def __str__(self):
        info = [f"Orden {self.id}:"]
        info.extend(str(x) for x in self.lista_computadores)
        return '\n'.join(info)
```

Para la clase `Orden` definimos una variable de clase que sirva para ir asignando un número de secuencia.

El método `__init__` recibe una cantidad indeterminada de argumentos. Al poner un asterico en la declaración de `lista_computadores`, Python captura en una lista todos los argumentos recibidos.

#### Demo

```
pc1 = Computador("LG", "Master")
pc2 = Computador("Apple", "Mac")
pc3 = Computador("Apple", "Macbook Air")

orden1 = Orden(pc1, pc2)
orden2 = Orden(pc1, pc2, pc3)
print(orden1)
print(orden2)
```

produce:

```
Orden 1:
PC LG Master
PC Apple Mac
Orden 2:
PC LG Master
PC Apple Mac
PC Apple Macbook Air

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: buenas y gracias por tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme!! al final lo pude solucionar, era el error tontísimo de no estar imprimiendo la clase Orden(), me di cuenta después de enviar la pregunta. Ahora estoy corrigiendo la sintaxis un poco. gracias de nuevo :)